# cx_freeze build doesn't allow program quitting

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I've tried with `exit(0)` in tkinter, `pygame.quit()` in pygme and other things in my cx_freeze build, but an error pops up when using `pygame.quit()` (which stops the whole program which is not intentional) and when I use `exit(0)` in tkinter it won't allow me to quit. It simply does nothing. Is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is odd, it should be correct but you can try this...

```
import sys
print("")
```

Comment: Thanks, pygame seems to be quitting now, but in my turtler programs where they draw things and then wait for an input I get this error: RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin